# Bulk/ automated removal of KB security update

Tags: microsoft-outlook, wsus

would like to know if there are any ways to do a bulk removal of KB 3203467, which has been causing attachment issues on Outlook. Mainly blocking attachments, stating that they are unsafe. Would like to know if there are any methods to do a bulk removal instead of doing it computer by computer. Tried the WSUS method but doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Do some research on how to uninstall a specific Windows Update with the KB number with a PowerShell or batch script, and then use that method for your task executing a script on each system however you may need to make that happen.

Comment: The bulk removal should work using WSUS (I recently verified that); can you elaborate what didn't work for you?